# Запись в файл русских символов

Tags: файлы, кодировка, php

```
 $fp = fopen("tmp/$filename",'wb');
 fwrite($fp, $description, strlen($description));
 fclose($fp);
```

В $description имеются русские символы. В файле получается запись, типа

> %u041A%u0430%u0436%u0435%u0442%u0441%u044F %u044F %u043F%u043E%u043D%u044F%u043B, %u043A%u0430%u043A %u0432%u0441%u0442%u0430%u0432%u043B%u044F%u0442%u044C %u0438%u0437%u043E%u0431%u0440%u0430%

Как решить проблему?

Answer (score 2):

Попробуй:

```
$fp=fopen("tmp/$filename","a+");
fwrite($fp, $description);
fclose($fp);
```